# Ocultar drawer item de Menu React-navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, navigation-drawer

Estoy intentando esconder/mostrar el botón de logout de mi drawer menu según el usuario este logeado o no, he puesto una función en el componente que decida si mostrar o no el botón en cada momento, pero solo funciona cuando el usuario entra la primera vez a la aplicación, después aunque el usuario se logee correctamente no se muestra el botón ya que el drawer navigation no se ha actualizado.
Habría algún modo de poder actualizar el drawer menu cuando el usuario se logee, para que aparezca el botón de logout? Y el procedimiento contrario al clicar el botón de logout...

**Navigation.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { createAppContainer } from "react-navigation";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "react-navigation-drawer";
import JornadaScreenStacks from "./JornadaStacks";
import CustomComponent from "./CustomDrawerComponent";

const NavigationStacks = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    Jornada: {
      screen: JornadaScreenStacks,
      navigationOptions: () => ({
        topBarLabel: "Jornada"
      })
    }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: props => <CustomComponent {...props} />,
    order: ["Jornada"]
  }
);

export default createAppContainer(NavigationStacks);
```

**CustomdrawerComponent.js**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { View, ScrollView, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import SafeAreaView from "react-native-safe-area-view";
import { DrawerNavigatorItems } from "react-navigation-drawer";
import { Icon } from "react-native-elements";
import { cerrarSesion, isLogeado } from "../utils/acces_control";
import {
  withNavigation,
  NavigationActions,
  StackActions
} from "react-navigation";

function CustomDrawerContentComponent(props) {
  const [es_logeado, setEs_logeado] = useState(false);
  const { navigation } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    async function logeado() {
      let login = await isLogeado();
      if (login === "true") {
        setEs_logeado(true);
      }
    }
    logeado();
  }, [es_logeado]);
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      {es_logeado && (
        <View style={styles.logoutButton}>
          <Icon
            type="material-community"
            name="power-standby"
            onPress={() => {
              cerrarSesion();
              const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
                index: 0,
                key: null,
                actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Jornada" })]
              });
              navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
            }}
          />
        </View>
      )}
      <SafeAreaView>
        <DrawerNavigatorItems {...props} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </ScrollView>
  );
}

export default withNavigation(CustomDrawerContentComponent);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  logoutButton: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    marginTop: 40
  }
});
```

**JornadaStacks.js**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { createStackNavigator } from "react-navigation-stack";
import JornadaScreen from "../screens/Jornada/Jornada";
import FormCodigoScreen from "../screens/Jornada/FormCodigo";
import EscanearCodigoScreen from "../screens/Jornada/QRScanner";
import PaneltrabajadorScreen from "../screens/Jornada/PanelTrabajador";

const JornadaScreenStacks = createStackNavigator({
  Jornada: {
    screen: JornadaScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: "Valida tu código",
      headerTintColor: "white",
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#753e9c"
      }
    })
  },
  FormCodigo: {
    screen: FormCodigoScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: "Introduce tu código",
      headerTintColor: "white",
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#753e9c"
      }
    })
  },
  EscanearCodigo: {
    screen: EscanearCodigoScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: "Escanea el código QR",
      headerTintColor: "white",
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#753e9c"
      }
    })
  },
  Paneltrabajador: {
    screen: PaneltrabajadorScreen,
    navigationOptions: () => ({
      title: "Mi Jornada",
      headerLeft: () => null,
      headerTintColor: "white",
      headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: "#753e9c"
      }
    })
  }
});

export default JornadaScreenStacks;
```

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import Navigation from "./app/navigations/Navigation";
import { navigationRef } from "./app/utils/RootNavigation";

export default function App() {
  return <Navigation ref={navigationRef} />;
}
```

**acces_control.js**

```
import { AsyncStorage } from "react-native";

export const isLogeado = async () => {
  try {
    // await AsyncStorage.setItem("loged", "null"); //Invalidar logeo
    return await AsyncStorage.getItem("loged");
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return false;
  }
};

export const cerrarSesion = async () => {
  try {
    AsyncStorage.setItem("loged", "false");
    return false;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return false;
  }
};

export const setSesion = () => {};
```

Comment: que hace la función `cerrarSesion`?

Comment: Pone en estado false un item del asyncstorage

Comment: por lo que veo nunca seteas a `false` el estado `es_logeado`, creo que luego de `cerrarSesion` deberías poner `setEs_logeado(false);`

Comment: Hey tienes razón había olvidado poner el estado de "es_logeado" a false, ahora oculta el botón al cerrar sesión, alguna idea para que lo muestre al iniciar? Si puedes ponlo como respuesta en lugar de comentario para cerrar la pregunta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente use UseContext en la Aplicación para poder mostrarlo/ocultarlo

**UserContext**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

let UserContext = React.createContext();
let { Provider, Consumer } = UserContext;

function UserProvider({ children }) {
  let [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  function login() {
    setUser(true);
  }

  function logout() {
    setUser(false);
  }
  return <Provider value={{ user, login, logout }}>{children}</Provider>;
}

export { UserProvider, Consumer as UserConsumer, UserContext };
```

Cuando se logea llamo a la función de "login()" y un condicional que comprueba el estado de user para mostrar/ocultar el botón, y en el botón de logout llamo a logout para ocultarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías hacer un toggle del estado `setEs_logeado`, luego del método de `cerrarSesion`

Answer (score 0):

En react con react-navigation tenemos la posibilidad de disparar eventos dependiendo de lo que hagamos...

Una solución viable sería enviar al drawernavigation con un param y ejecutar de nuevo lo que necesites en la función.

```
import { NavigationEvents } from "react-navigation";
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <NavigationEvents
          onWillFocus={() => {
            //Call whatever logic or dispatch redux actions and update the screen!
          }}
        />
        <Text>Home</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Y en este caso lo usarías en el navigation?

Comment: sí.............

Comment: podrías poner un ejemplo funcional? O sea como lo aplicarías en el navigation.js